# How to handle windows event (message) the ReactiveUI way?

Tags: wpf, windows, events, reactiveui

I'm new to ReactiveUI and currently happy with it.
But I have one question: How to handle windows event/message the ReactiveUI way?

In mvvmlight, it's like this:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}"
                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But I don't know how to do it in ReactiveUI.
Maybe it's something similar to

```
MessageBus.Current.Listen<KeyUpEventArgs>()  
    .Where(e => e.KeyCode == KeyCode.Up)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Up Pressed!"));
```

but I don't know how to do it for mainframe's `Closing` event specifically.

I have read somewhere that the author of ReactiveUI is not strongly against *code behind* code (maybe I remember wrong), what's the suggested way then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a separate Nuget package [ReactiveUI Events](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reactiveui-events/), which contains helpers (extension methods) exposing events as `IObservables` which you can use inside views. It is described [in the docs](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/events/).

Basically, your code behind in the view will contain something similar to this:

```
this.Events().Closing
    .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Bye!"));
```

Take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22485360/1108916) as well.

Comment: Thanks! I actually use [reactiveui-events.Net40](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reactiveui-events.Net40) instead because I'm using .net 4.0.